# Remove Alternate Elements from ArrayList in java 7

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have an array of String containing below elements

```
5.0,99,5.5,100,6.0,101
```

Now what I want to do I need to remove all the decimal value in string format like `5.0,5.5` and `6.0`

so my final array should contain elements `99,100,101`

so what I'd done so far is show in below code

```
public static String[] deleteElement(String[] str_array) {
        //String[] str_array = {"item1","item2","item3"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
        
        list.remove("5.0");
        list.remove("5.5");
        list.remove("6.0");
        return str_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

I have hardcoded the values which is quite bad practice as the values in future may be more than the current values, so I want a way to remove by using `index`.

I have tried to remove using `remove(index)` also, using even index positioning like 0,2,4,but what actually happening is, after deletion of `5.0` , elements are shifted left side, so 100 comes into the 2nd position, and in next iteration 100 deleted.

So is there any way where I can construct a generic function so if there are more elements in decimal value so it can also be deleted.

**NOTE**:
The string decimal values will always be residing on even index positioning.

Comment: parse the `ArrayList` from `n-1` to `0` and use `contains(".")` method and if it does just `remove` it

Comment: Hi, demonstrate the same in my code

Comment: Okay in a min. i'll post a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have traversed the `List` from `list.size() -1` to `0`
So that number arent pushed in front.
when you traverse it from `0` to `size of  the list` and then if you delete an element `1` element is skipped cause `size()` of the list decreases and `i` keeps incrementing.
eg.["5.0","6.1","5.5","100","6.0","6.6"]
when you traverse form `0` to `size() - 1`
i = 0 : 
`5.0` is seen and removed and then the list is like `["6.1","5.5","100","6.0","6.6"]` where now `6.1` is at `0` index.

i = 1: 
`5.5` is removed and then  the list is like
`["6.1","100","6.0","6.6"]` where now `100` is at `1` index.

and so on.

But when traverse from `size-1` to `0` it will remove every single element without the fear of missing any `decimal` number.
Try this on your own and you will get to know why it is working and why `0` to `n-1` isn't working.

```
            String arr[] = {"5.0","99","5.5","100","6.0","101"};
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
            for(int i = list.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                String number = list.get(i);
                if(number.contains(".")) {
                    list.remove(number);
                }
            }
            
            for(String val : list) {
                System.out.println(val);
            }
```

output:

```
99
100
101
```

Comment: That exactly what I am looking for, that make sense

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the below approach, it worked fine for me !!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DecimalRemoval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("5.0","99","5.5","100","6.0","101");
        List<String> resultant = new ArrayList<>(lst.size());
        
        for(String element: lst) {
            if(! element.contains("."))
                resultant.add(element);
        }
        
        System.out.println(resultant);
    }
}
```

[image]

Also attaching the screenshot from my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers *work* but are more verbose than required:

```
list.removeIf(str -> str.contains("."));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and suggesting the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just stream the array and filter out the unwanted values.

```
String[] v = {"5.0","99","5.5","100","6.0","101"};
v = Arrays.stream(v)
        .filter(str->!str.contains("."))
        .toArray(String[]::new);


System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
```

Prints

```
[99, 100, 101]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution can be:

1. Instantiate an `ArrayList<String>`.
2. Navigate the array and add the element to the list if it does not contain `.`
3. Finally convert the list to an array and return the same.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static String[] deleteElement(String[] str_array) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : str_array) {
            if (!s.contains(".")) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }

        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deleteElement(new String[] { "5.0", "99", "5.5", "100", "6.0", "101" })));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[99, 100, 101]
```

Alternatively, you can do it in the way you are already doing but it is not so efficient way. Since you are first adding all the elements to the list and then removing the unwanted ones, therefore it is not so efficient as the one suggested above.

```
public static String[] deleteElement(String[] str_array) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
    for (String s : str_array) {
        if (s.contains(".")) {
            list.remove(s);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Java 8 users ,
Best solution would be using the Java lambda expressions**.

```
list.removeIf(element -> element.contains("."));
```